# How to find the nearest two numbers of a custom function

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, lodash

Given a number, how can I find the nearest two numbers which starts with 1, 2.5 or 5? (10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000...endless)

The result should be the nearest nearest higher number, and one below it.

For example: the number 420 should return 250 and 500.
For example: the number 10 should return 10 and 25.

Can use Lodash if it's helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: First, arrays can't be endless because they are held in memory, which is obviously finite. Are you talking about an infinite [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)? And second, are the numbers in a particular order?

Comment: It's not an array, I'm just looking for the two nearest numbers which are rounded to 1, 2.5 and 5. 
I'm given only one number, another example:
for the number 1,200,000 I would like to get 1,000,000 and 2,500,000.

Comment: @RonenTeva If it's not an array then where do you want to find those numbers from? and what if the given number is 10 for this list. what should be the answer?

Comment: I still don't quite understand. By nearest, do you mean the two numbers on either side? Or do you mean the smallest difference, in which case 1,200,000 is closer to 500,000 than it is to 2,500,000. Or do the numbers have to have the same number of digits? I think this is definitely answerable, but we need more information about precisely the problem you are trying to solve. What happens if the number is, say, 99? What about 100?

Comment: @AsifRahaman It's not an array, I'm looking for a mathematical way to get those numbers. For the number 10 the answer should be 10 and 25.

Comment: @McMath Two nearest numbers on either side. (or same number and the nearest higher one, following Asif's comment)

Comment: @RonenTeva what i actually wanted to know if those numbers are stored somewhere and you wanna fetch numbers from there or are you trying to generate those? And you said you are looking for a mathematical way to get those numbers but from where? suppose if there is only the given number, for example 10 then why can't I pick up 11 or 9? does that mean all numbers are pre generated and stored somewhere maybe not in an array?

Comment: @AsifRahaman the numbers are 1, 2.5 and 5, adding as many zeros as needed (10, 25, 50, etc...). This is not an example, those are the real numbers and they can be hard coded.

Comment: @RonenTeva The 10 example doesn't make sense. What do you mean by closest? Because the two closest number of 10 should be 10 and 5.

Comment: You need a more clear definition of what you are looking for.  My naive interpretation is that 10 is closer to 10 and 5 (total diff 5) than it is to 10 and 25 (total diff 15)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek You're right. I've updated the question.

Comment: @JonSG You're right. I've updated the question.

Comment: How does your update help?  Let's take 11.  Why is 11 not (10, 5) total diff 7 vs (10, 25) total diff 15?

Comment: @JonSG I meant that I need the nearest higher one, updated again :)

Comment: cool, now it is much clearer... I think @McMath has your answer then given the updated requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I understand based on your comments.

```
// Finds the two numbers on each side for any number.
function nearest(n) {
  let m = multiplier(n);
  return nearest10(n / m).map(n => n * m);
}

// Finds the two numbers on each side for numbers between 1 and 10.
function nearest10(n) {
  return n < 2.5 ? [1, 2.5] : n < 5 ? [2.5, 5] : [5, 10];
}

// Returns the neareast power of 10 less than or equal to n.
function multiplier(n) {
  return Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(n)));
}
```

And here is a sample of the results:

```
console.log(nearest(2));     // [1, 2.5]
console.log(nearest(420));   // [250, 500]
console.log(nearest(79310)); // [50000, 100000]
```

Answer (score 1):

First write the number in scientific notation to get rid of the scale.

```
420 = 4.2x10^2
```

Then locate the mantissa among `[1, 2.5)`, `[2.5, 5)`, `[5, 10)`.

```
4.2 in [2.5, 5)
```

And transfer the exponent,

```
2.5x10^2 = 250, 5x10^2 = 500
```

This is better done using base 10 logarithms,

```
L= log(X) / log(10)
E= floor(L)
L= L - E
if      L < log(2.5), LB=       pow(10, N), UB= 2.5 * pow(10,N)
else if L < log(5)  , LB= 2.5 * pow(10, N), UB=   5 * pow(10,N)
else                  LB=   5 * pow(10, N), UB=  10 * pow(10,N)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findPrevAndNext(x){
  // returns the next highest value and previous
  // lower value in the infinite series 
  // [1, 2.5, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, ...]

  var top = 5;

  while(top < x){
    top = top * 10;
  }

  var mid = top / 2;   // ex: 5/2 = 2.5
  var bot = top / 5;   // ex: 5/5 = 1

  var prev, next = 0;

  if(x >= mid){
    prev = mid;
    next = top;
  }
  else if(x >= bot){
    prev = bot;
    next = mid;
  }
  else{
    prev = bot / 2;
    next = bot
  }

  return Array(prev,next);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o44t0t65/1/